# BASH MySQL - Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, csv

I have created the following table using sql cli on a Linux terminal:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `songs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `songs` (
      `track_id` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
      `title` text,
      `song_id` text,
      `release` text,
      `artist_id` text,
      `artist_mbid` text,
      `artist_name` text,
      `duration` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `artist_familiarity` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `artist_hotttnesss` double DEFAULT NULL,
      `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`track_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am executing a bash script that will load data from a local CSV file into the database table `songs`.

```
nano importSQL.sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
while read column1 column2 column3 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11
      do
        echo "INSERT INTO cost (column1, ... ,column11) VALUES ('$column1', '$column2', '$column3', '$column4', '$column5', '$column6', '$column7', '$column8', '$column9', '$column10', '$column11');"

    done < a.csv | mysql -u root -abc song_db;
```

When I execute this query, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'artist_hotttness' in 'field list'
```

Any help on how I should avoid this?

Comment: You have an extra `s` for `artist_hotttness` in the table definition.

Comment: You don't want to do it this way. This is begging for SQL injections. MySQL has [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to read CSV files, and you should use that.

Comment: Thanks Abhik. @Wintermute, I am unable to do that as I cannot provide a path to my CSV from mysql cli. Not sure why

Comment: Turns out it was a permission error. Got it sorted! Thanks!